# value of filter criterion for field 'Price__c' must be of type string and should be enclosed in quotes

Tags: lightning-aura-components

value of filter criterion for field 'Price__c' must be of type string and should be enclosed in quotes

System.QueryException: value of filter criterion for field 'Price__c' must be of type string and should be enclosed in quotes

=============================================================

```
            var dispRating='';

   var prices = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="price#"]');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(prices, function(pricesSelected) {    
        if(pricesSelected.checked)
        {
            alert('>>>>>'+pricesSelected.id.substr(6));
            if(k==0)
            {
                dispRating = '(asb_App__r.Price__c = ' + pricesSelected.id.substr(6);
            }
            else
            {
                dispRating = dispRating + ' Or asb_App__r.Price__c = ' + pricesSelected.id.substr(6);
            }
           k++;
     //         alert("Checked: "+ratingsSelected.checked + "Rating:" + ratingsSelected.id.substr(7) );   
        }
    });
    if(dispRating != '')
    {            
        dispRating = dispRating + ') ';
    }
    alert(dispRating);

    if(strCategory != '')
    {
        strWhere = ' where ' + strCategory;
    }

    if (strLanguage !='')
    {
        if(strWhere != '')
        {
            strWhere = strWhere + ' And ' + strLanguage;
        }
        else
        {
            strWhere = ' where ' + strLanguage;
        }
    }

    if (dispRating != '')
    {
        if(strWhere != '')
        {
            strWhere = strWhere + ' And ' + dispRating;
        }
        else
        {
            strWhere = ' where ' + dispRating;
        }    
    }

    alert('strWhere>>>>>>>>>'+strWhere);
```

---

Comment: sWHERE contains an invalid filter. The problem is not in this method, but from the method calling this method. Please **[edit]** in your Lightning Controller/Helper where you're building the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
        if(k==0)
        {
            dispRating = '(asb_App__r.Price__c = ' + pricesSelected.id.substr(6);
        }
        else
        {
            dispRating = dispRating + ' Or asb_App__r.Price__c = ' + pricesSelected.id.substr(6);
        }
```

Price__c, being a picklist, must be enclosed in quotes. You'll want to make it look something like this:

```
        if(k==0)
        {
            dispRating = "(asb_App__r.Price__c = '" + pricesSelected.id.substr(6) + "'";
        }
        else
        {
            dispRating = dispRating + " Or asb_App__r.Price__c = '" + pricesSelected.id.substr(6) + "'";
        }
```

Also, as an side, you could skip the special logic and optimize the code using `IN`:

```
var dispRatingFilters = [], dispRating;
var prices = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="price#"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(prices, function(pricesSelected) {    
  if(pricesSelected.checked) {
    dispRatingFilters.push("'"+ pricesSelcted.id.substr(6)+"'");
  }
});
dispRating = "asb_App__r.Price__c IN ("+dispRatingFilters.join(",")+")";
```